# Can a webcam stream directly to an RTMP Flash Server without a computer?

Tags: stream, video-streaming, webcam, flash-media-server, ip-camera

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to stream directly from a webcam (IP Camera / Network Camera) to an RTMP Flash Server.

The purpose is to be able to set up a camera at a location and be able to stream directly from it to streaming services such as DaCast or justin.tv without the need to have it hooked up to a computer that does the encoding. All it would need is a wireless connection.

Technically the camera would have to have it's own encoder (H.264) and a place where you can configure the Flash Media Server to stream to within it's built-in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CamStreamer RTMP client](http://camstreamer.com) - An application which is running directly in Axis IP camera. The camera with CamStreamer pushes the video to any RTMP streaming service (LiveStream, uStream, YouTube Live,...).

Answer (score -1):

Parts of this answer comes from: [AskUbuntu: Security camera system server](https://askubuntu.com/a/57842/9598)

Certain IP Cameras, in several flavors, brand names and models, provide their own web page for setup/preview/monitor, from which you can extract the portions of code that you can use in your own project in a website.

You don't say what do you have in mind by streaming to justin.tv or other web based streaming service but if what you wish to achieve is to get the benefit of the popularity of the web based streaming service itself to gain audience, then this solution IS NOT FOR YOU.

But if you are using a web based streaming service just to gather the portions of code in order to be used in a customized website of your own, then you can use the code provided by your own IP Camera.

> As far as I know, the majority of the IP cameras, as those shown in
>   [this virtual shop](https://askubuntu.com/a/57842/9598), starting from $ 945.00 Mexican Pesos (almost
>   100 US Dollars), and this [D-Link DC-900](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=270) (the majority of them
>   tested by me) resolves the motion detection, scheduled recording and
>   remote control by itself (there are just a few which features 360°
>   movement, remote controlled).
>
> How to reach your cameras from outside is as easy as getting a Dynamic
>   Domain Name Service and to use it in your modem/router or, if you have
>   fixed IP then you don't have a problem, you will also be in need to
>   route the specific ports to the cameras and make the cameras respond
>   to the petitions of a specific port.
>
> Everything can be monitored/controlled via web browser, like in this
>   example of my security system which is embedding 3 cameras (1 of them
>   remote controlled) in a single web page. (blurred where needed for
>   privacy).
>
> [image]
>
> The remote controlled camera is the one [shown here](http://www.e-tronic-shop.com/mystore/esp/detalle.php?idc=0&id=43), with two-way
>   audio (yes, you can speak to people close to the camera), wireless and
>   infra-red night vision. (Sorry, I don't sell these cameras but I
>   purchased over there in Mexico City.)

In the examples provided here I am using the portions of code of the original IP Camera web page monitoring system, as shown in the next picture:

Original DCS-900 Camera's Web Based Application

[image]

So I think this can be done directly from the IP Camera web application but as I mentioned before, if what you wish is to get advantage on the web based streaming service (for getting audience), you may wish to consider a different choice.

Good luck!

Comment: You are correct. I am trying to stream from many cameras to many viewers in the cheapest way possible. DaCast for example takes in an RTMP feed... so if I could just find a camera that directly provides this feeds without middle hardware that'd be the best solution for me.